# How do I center align an embedded soundcloud widget?

Tags: html, css, widget, soundcloud

I used the widget API from soundcloud and embedded the widget into my HTML file but I am having trouble center aligning it.

The HTML code is

```
<iframe width="50%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" align="middle" src="musiclink&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

As you can see I tried align="middle" but it did not work. 
I tried align="left" and that worked but for some reason align="middle" did not work. Furthermore, I went into the API code and tried to change the CSS styling to

```
.widget {
    background-position: center center;
}
```

But that did not work either

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the iframe with a div:

```
<div style='text-align:center'>
<iframe width="50%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" align="center" src="musiclink&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`middle` is a value for `valign`.
Use `align="center"` instead.

More on `valign`: [Here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp)

More on `align`: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_align.asp)

Answer (score 0):

put a div around the iframe and set the left and right margin to auto. it will center this div inside of it's container.

```
<div style='margin:0 auto;'>
<iframe width="50%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" align="center" src="musiclink&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
</div>
```